# final link failed ssh

Tags: macos, ssh, make, c

make task_1
gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Werror task_1.c -lsuperkarel -lcurses -o task_1
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Disk quota exceeded
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:9: task_1] Error 1